# SwiftUI @FetchRequest in ForEach request limit

Tags: swiftui, swift5, nsfetchrequest

```
struct DashboardRingAcftView: View {

    @FetchRequest(entity: ACFTScores.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ACFTScores.createdAt, ascending: false)]) var acftScores: FetchedResults<ACFTScores>

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("ACFT Snapshot")
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: CGFloat(0)) {
```

> I'm trying to call the request in the ForEach but over 5 requests it crashes. I've tried .forEach in a closure to functions inside the viewBuilder... Not sure what to do but I need 6 requests to evaluate the equation.

```
                ForEach(acftScores, id: \.self) { score in
                    RingViewAcft(width: 44, height: 44, ringProgress: Int(score.totalScore), recordDate: score.createdAt ?? Date(), recordLabel: "ACFT Date", color:
                        self.colorCategory(
                        scoreMDL: Int(score.totalPointsMDL),
                        scoreSPT: Int(score.totalPointsSPT),
                        scoreHRP: Int(score.totalPointsHRP),
                        scoreSDC: Int(score.totalPointsSDC),
                        scoreLTK: Int(score.totalPointsLTK),
                        score2MR: Int(score.totalPoints2MR)))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see anything bad here. How many of `acftScores` returned? What's inside `RingViewAcft`?

Comment: It literally won't call on more than 5 returns in the ForEach... RingViewACFT is a simple ring with a trim from 1...100. I'm trying to return a color for the ring against the total points. this was easy for a single score but total points for each of the six categories takes the lowest event. for instance 100Points, 100Points, 100Points, 65Points - this would return a color for 65 points not the average